# Sort json array in PHP by date?

Tags: php, json, parsing, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of news items that have been converted from xml (rss) to json. I'd like to have them sorted by date order after the feeds have been combined but I am not sure on  the best way to achieve it.

The json response looks like:

```
{ "success":true,
"message":"",
"data":{
"title":"Feed Name",
"item":[{
"title":"test",
"pubdate":"Sun, 20 Oct 2013 21:36:42 GMT"}]
}
}
```

Comment: Specially when *just searching* the Stack brings an answer to 90%-95% of our code needs.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. I am aware I need to use usort but I am unsure as to how to achieve it with items nested this deep in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it in PHP, you'd first decode it to a PHP array:

```
 $data = json_decode($yourJsonVariable, true);
```

Now with your data as above, that is going to give you an array that looks something like:

```
 array(
   'success' => true,
   'data' => array(
     'title' => 'Feed Name',
     'item' => array(
       0 => array(
         'title' => 'test',
         'pubdate' => 'Sun, 20 Oct 2013 21:36:42 GMT'
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

So using that, you can figure out how you'd like your sorting function to work. What is unclear, though, is if you are trying to sort just the elements of the `item` array, or if you are trying to do some more complex sort (since you mentioned "when the feeds are combined").

To sort only the `item` array is a fairly simple task, sine each element is just an array with two elements of its own, one named `title` and another named `pubdate`. In that case your sort function looks something like:

```
 usort($data['data']['item'], function($a, $b) {
   return (strtotime($a['pubdate']) < strtotime($b['pubdate']) -1 : 1);
 });
```

If you need to sort the entire array or a different part of it, you should be able to adapt that function to do so.

Comment: Massive thanks, I need to sort multiple feeds but this is a great starting point. Thanks!