# Change order of JSON in PHP without key/value pair

Tags: php, json

I have a situation where i need to sort a JSON object by date. I've searched for solutions online and everything points in the direction of PHP's [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function, but [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808783/how-to-sort-a-json-array-with-php) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483435/sort-json-array-in-php-by-date) have a key/value pair to sort on.

This is how i load the feed:

```
$ret = file_get_contents($url);
$res = json_encode($ret);
```

Wich results in the following JSON

```
{  
   "2015-12-14":{  
      "direction":"S",
      "snowfall":0.0,
      [..]
  },
   "2015-12-15":{  
      "direction":"S",
      "snowfall":3.0,
      [..]
   },
   "2015-12-12":{  
      "direction":"SE",
      "snowfall":0.0,
      [..]
   },
   "2015-12-13":{  
      "direction":"S",
      "snowfall":0.0,
      [..]
   },
   "2015-12-10":{  
      "direction":"E",
      "snowfall":0.0,
      [..]
   },
   "2015-12-11":{  
      "direction":"S",
      "snowfall":0.0,
      [..]
   }
}
```

As you can see, the data is not properly ordered by date, but the date value is the key so how can i sort the object by date (2015-12-10, 2015-12-11, 2015-12-12, 2015-12-13, 2015-12-14, 2015-12-15)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = '{  
   "2015-12-14":{  

      "direction":"S",

      "snowfall":0.0

  },

   "2015-12-15":{  

      "direction":"S",

      "snowfall":3.0

   },

   "2015-12-12":{  

      "direction":"SE",

      "snowfall":0.0

   },

   "2015-12-13":{  

      "direction":"S",

      "snowfall":0.0

   },

   "2015-12-10":{  

      "direction":"E",

      "snowfall":0.0

   },

   "2015-12-11":{  

      "direction":"S",

      "snowfall":0.0

   }

}';

$array = get_object_vars(json_decode($json));

ksort($array);

echo json_encode((object)$array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the data before encoding it, with something like [ksort](http://php.net/ksort):

```
$ret = file_get_contents($url);
ksort($ret);
$res = json_encode($ret);
```

That way, the array that `$ret` seems to return will be sorted by key (the date) and then be encoded in that sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), which can sort your array by key.

You can use sort flags as well, which are well-described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).